# Is it possible to implement dynamic getters/setters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, metaprogramming, getter-setter

I am aware of how to create getters and setters for properties whose names one already knows, by doing something like this:

```
// A trivial example:
function MyObject(val){
    this.count = 0;
    this.value = val;
}
MyObject.prototype = {
    get value(){
        return this.count < 2 ? "Go away" : this._value;
    },
    set value(val){
        this._value = val + (++this.count);
    }
};
var a = new MyObject('foo');

alert(a.value); // --> "Go away"
a.value = 'bar';
alert(a.value); // --> "bar2"
```

Now, my question is, is it possible to define sort of catch-all getters and setters like these?  I.e., create getters and setters for any property name which *isn't* already defined.

The concept is possible in PHP using the `__get()` and `__set()` magic methods (see [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for information on these), so I'm really asking is there a JavaScript equivalent to these?

Needless to say, I'd ideally like a solution that is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: I managed to do it, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18043786/1115652) for how.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

This changed as of the ES2015 (aka "ES6") specification: JavaScript now has [*proxies*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/reflection.html#sec-proxy-objects). Proxies let you create objects that are true proxies for (facades on) other objects. Here's a simple example that turns any property values that are strings to all caps on retrieval, and returns `"missing"` instead of `undefined` for a property that doesn't exist:

```js
"use strict";
if (typeof Proxy == "undefined") {
    throw new Error("This browser doesn't support Proxy");
}
let original = {
    example: "value",
};
let proxy = new Proxy(original, {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
        if (Reflect.has(target, name)) {
            let rv = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
            if (typeof rv === "string") {
                rv = rv.toUpperCase();
            }
            return rv;
        }
        return "missing";
      }
});
console.log(`original.example = ${original.example}`); // "original.example = value"
console.log(`proxy.example = ${proxy.example}`);       // "proxy.example = VALUE"
console.log(`proxy.unknown = ${proxy.unknown}`);       // "proxy.unknown = missing"
original.example = "updated";
console.log(`original.example = ${original.example}`); // "original.example = updated"
console.log(`proxy.example = ${proxy.example}`);       // "proxy.example = UPDATED"
```

Operations you don't override have their default behavior. In the above, all we override is `get`, but there's a whole list of operations you can hook into.

In the `get` handler function's arguments list:

- `target` is the object being proxied (`original`, in our case).
- `name` is (of course) the name of the property being retrieved, which is usually a string but could also be a Symbol.
- `receiver` is the object that should be used as `this` in the getter function if the property is an accessor rather than a data property. In the normal case this is the proxy or something that inherits from it, but it *can* be anything since the trap may be triggered by `Reflect.get`.

This lets you create an object with the catch-all getter and setter feature you want:

```js
"use strict";
if (typeof Proxy == "undefined") {
    throw new Error("This browser doesn't support Proxy");
}
let obj = new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, name, receiver) {
        if (!Reflect.has(target, name)) {
            console.log("Getting non-existent property '" + name + "'");
            return undefined;
        }
        return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
    },
    set(target, name, value, receiver) {
        if (!Reflect.has(target, name)) {
            console.log(`Setting non-existent property '${name}', initial value: ${value}`);
        }
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
    }
});

console.log(`[before] obj.example = ${obj.example}`);
obj.example = "value";
console.log(`[after] obj.example = ${obj.example}`);
```

The output of the above is:

```
Getting non-existent property 'example'
[before] obj.example = undefined
Setting non-existent property 'example', initial value: value
[after] obj.example = value
```

Note how we get the "non-existent" message when we try to retrieve `example` when it doesn't yet exist, and again when we create it, but not after that.

---

**Answer from 2011** *(obsoleted by the above, still relevant to environments limited to ES5 features like Internet Explorer)*:

No, JavaScript doesn't have a catch-all property feature. The accessor syntax you're using is covered in [Section 11.1.5](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.5) of the spec, and doesn't offer any wildcard or something like that.

You could, of course, implement a function to do it, but I'm guessing you probably don't want to use `f = obj.prop("example");` rather than `f = obj.example;` and `obj.prop("example", value);` rather than `obj.example = value;` (which would be necessary for the function to handle unknown properties).

FWIW, the getter function (I didn't bother with setter logic) would look something like this:

```
MyObject.prototype.prop = function(propName) {
    if (propName in this) {
        // This object or its prototype already has this property,
        // return the existing value.
        return this[propName];
    }

    // ...Catch-all, deal with undefined property here...
};
```

But again, I can't imagine you'd really want to do that, because of how it changes how you use the object.

Answer (score 19):

**Preface:**

[T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891968/1599699) mentions a `Proxy`, which will be needed for a catch-all getter/setter for properties which don't exist, as the OP was asking for. Depending on what behavior is actually wanted with dynamic getters/setters, a `Proxy` may not actually be necessary though; or, potentially, you may want to use a combination of a `Proxy` with what I'll show you below.

*(P.S. I have experimented with `Proxy` thoroughly in Firefox on Linux recently and have found it to be very capable, but also somewhat confusing/difficult to work with and get right. More importantly, I have also found it to be quite slow (at least in relation to how optimized JavaScript tends to be nowadays) - I'm talking in the realm of deca-multiples slower.)*

---

To implement dynamically created getters and setters specifically, you can use [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) or [`Object.defineProperties()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties). This is also quite fast.

The gist is that you can define a getter and/or setter on an object like so:

```js
let obj = {};
let val = 0;
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'prop', { //<- This object is called a "property descriptor".
  //Alternatively, use: `get() {}`
  get: function() {
    return val;
  },
  //Alternatively, use: `set(newValue) {}`
  set: function(newValue) {
    val = newValue;
  }
});

//Calls the getter function.
console.log(obj.prop);
let copy = obj.prop;
//Etc.

//Calls the setter function.
obj.prop = 10;
++obj.prop;
//Etc.
```

Several things to note here:

- You cannot use the `value` property in the property descriptor (*not* shown above) simultaneously with `get` and/or `set`; from the docs:

  > Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors. A *data descriptor* is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An *accessor descriptor* is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be both.
- Thus, you'll note that I created a `val` property *outside* of the `Object.defineProperty()` call/property descriptor. This is standard behavior.
- As per the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34478778/1599699), don't set `writable` to `true` in the property descriptor if you use `get` or `set`.
- You might want to consider setting `configurable` and `enumerable`, however, depending on what you're after; from the docs:

  > **configurable**
  >
  > - `true` if and only if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object.
  > - **Defaults to false.**
  >
  > ---
  >
  > **enumerable**
  >
  > - `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object.
  > - **Defaults to false.**

---

On this note, these may also be of interest:

- [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames): gets all properties of an object, even non-enumerable ones (AFAIK this is the **only** way to do so!).
- [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor): gets the property descriptor of an object, the object that was passed to `Object.defineProperty()` above.
- [`obj.propertyIsEnumerable(prop);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable): for an individual property on a specific object instance, call this function on the object instance to determine whether the specific property is enumerable or not.

Comment: I'm afraid you've misread the question. The OP specifically asked for *catch all* like [PHP's `__get` and `__set`](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php). `defineProperty` doesn't handle that case. From the question: *"I.e., create getters and setters for any property name which **isn't** already defined."* (their emphasis). `defineProperty` defines properties in advance. The only way to do what the OP asked for is a proxy.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see. You are technically correct, though the question wasn't very clear. I've adjusted my answer accordingly. Also, some may actually want a combination of our answers (I personally do).

Comment: @Andrew when I asked this question back in 2011 the use-case I had in mind was a library that can return an object on which the user could call `obj.whateverProperty` such that the library can intercept that with a generic getter and be given the property name the user tried to access.  Hence the requirement for 'catch-all getters and setters'.

Comment: @Andrew your answer was helpful to me

Answer (score 5):

The following could be an original approach to this problem:

```
var obj = {
  emptyValue: null,
  get: function(prop){
    if(typeof this[prop] == "undefined")
        return this.emptyValue;
    else
        return this[prop];
  },
  set: function(prop,value){
    this[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

In order to use it the properties should be passed as strings.
So here is an example of how it works:

```
//To set a property
obj.set('myProperty','myValue');

//To get a property
var myVar = obj.get('myProperty');
```

**Edit:**
An improved, more object-oriented approach based on what I proposed is the following:

```
function MyObject() {
    var emptyValue = null;
    var obj = {};
    this.get = function(prop){
        return (typeof obj[prop] == "undefined") ? emptyValue : obj[prop];
    };
    this.set = function(prop,value){
        obj[prop] = value;
    };
}

var newObj = new MyObject();
newObj.set('myProperty','MyValue');
alert(newObj.get('myProperty'));
```

You can see it working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/443tgedL/3/).

Comment: This doesn't work.  You can't define a getter without specifying the name of the property.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Check this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oga7ne4x/ It works. You only have to pass the property names as strings.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying.  I thought you were trying to use the get()/set() language feature, not writing your own get()/set().  I still don't like this solution though because it doesn't really solve the original problem.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Well, I wrote it's an original approach. It provides a different way to solve the problem, even though it doesn't solve the problem where you have an existing code that uses a more traditional approach. But it's good if you are starting from scratch. Surely not worthy a downvote...

Comment: @JohnKurlak See if now it looks better! :)

Comment: What you've posted is more reusable, but every time I've run into the problem of wanting dynamic getters and setters (even when starting from scratch) a solution like this is too much overhead for what I want.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Well, overhead is what you get when you need solutions which are not provided natively. Whether it's too much or not, is a subjective thing to decide. Thanks for expressing your thought! :)

Comment: I suppose.  Usually when I'm looking on StackOverflow, I'd rather quickly see that there is no native way to do what I want than to have to parse through 5 solutions to see what they're actually doing.  Either way, I removed the downvote in case someone finds your answer helpful.

Comment: @JohnKurlak Thanks! :) Anyway it was useful, because this conversation with you encouraged me to improve my answer. So, thanks for that as well! :)

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62727149/1599699) shows the equivalent of this without the need to explicitly call any functions.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for something and I figured out on my own.

```
/*
    This function takes an object and converts to a proxy object.
    It also takes care of proxying nested objectsa and array.
*/
let getProxy = (original) => {

    return new Proxy(original, {

        get(target, name, receiver) {
            let rv = Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
            return rv;
        },

        set(target, name, value, receiver) {

            // Proxies new objects 
            if(typeof value === "object"){
                value = getProxy(value);
            }

            return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
        }
    })
}

let first = {};
let proxy = getProxy(first);

/*
    Here are the tests
*/

proxy.name={}                               // object
proxy.name.first={}                         // nested object
proxy.name.first.names=[]                   // nested array 
proxy.name.first.names[0]={first:"vetri"}   // nested array with an object

/*
    Here are the serialised values
*/
console.log(JSON.stringify(first))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
console.log(JSON.stringify(proxy))  // {"name":{"first":{"names":[{"first":"vetri"}]}}}
```

Comment: Given an object, return me an object signals on CRUD on its properties.

Answer (score -6):

```
var x={}
var propName = 'value' 
var get = Function("return this['" + propName + "']")
var set = Function("newValue", "this['" + propName + "'] = newValue")
var handler = { 'get': get, 'set': set, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
Object.defineProperty(x, propName, handler)
```

this works for me

Comment: Using `Function()` like that is like using `eval`.
Just put directly the functions as parameters of `defineProperty`. Or, if for some reason you insist to dynamically create `get` and `set`, then use a high-order function that creates the function and return it, like `var get = (function(propName) { return function() { return this[propName]; };})('value');`