# Javascript - catch access to property of object

Tags: javascript, object-properties

Is it possible to capture when a (any) property of an object is accessed, or attempting to be accessed?

Example:

I have created custom object `Foo`

```
var Foo = (function(){
    var self = {};
    //... set a few properties
    return self;
})();
```

Then there is some action against `Foo` - someone tries to access property `bar`

```
Foo.bar
```

Is there way (prototype, perhaps) to capture this? `bar` may be undefined on `Foo`. I could suffice with capturing any attempted access to undefined properties.

For instance, if `bar` is undefined on `Foo`, and `Foo.bar` is attempted, something like:

```
Foo.prototype.undefined = function(){
    var name = this.name; //name of property they attempted to access (bar)
    Foo[name] = function(){
        //...do something
    };
    return Foo[name];
}
```

But functional, unlike my example.

**Concept**

```
Foo.* = function(){
}
```

**Background**

If I have a custom function, I can listen for every time this function is called (see below). Just wondering if it's possible with property access.

```
Foo = function(){};
Foo.prototype.call = function(thisArg){
    console.log(this, thisArg);
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Not unless you create getters and setters for the properties and "hide" the real properties

Comment: @megawac can you post a short example as an answer? I feel I don't need much, just a push in the right direction.

Comment: Pretty sure it can't be done

Comment: @RandyHall: He means you would have to change all property accesses to method calls EVERYWHERE in your code. myObj.getFoo(), not myObj.foo and myObj.setFoo(val)

Comment: @megawac: And that wouldn't work for properties that don't exist.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in ES2015+, using the [Proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies). It's not possible in ES5 and earlier, not even with polyfills.

It took me a while, but I finally found [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript/7891968#7891968) to this question. See that answer for all the details on proxies and such.

Here's the proxy example from that answer:

```
const obj = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Getting non-existant property '" + name + "'");
            return undefined;
        }
        return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
    },
    set: function(target, name, value, receiver) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Setting non-existant property '" + name + "', initial value: " + value);
        }
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
    }
});

console.log("[before] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "baz";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
```

Live Copy:

```js
"use strict";

const obj = new Proxy({}, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Getting non-existant property '" + name + "'");
            return undefined;
        }
        return Reflect.get(target, name, receiver);
    },
    set: function(target, name, value, receiver) {
        if (!(name in target)) {
            console.log("Setting non-existant property '" + name + "', initial value: " + value);
        }
        return Reflect.set(target, name, value, receiver);
    }
});

console.log("[before] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "bar";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
obj.foo = "baz";
console.log("[after] obj.foo = " + obj.foo);
```

When run, that outputs:

```
Getting non-existant property 'foo'
[before] obj.foo = undefined
Setting non-existant property 'foo', initial value: bar
[after] obj.foo = bar
[after] obj.foo = baz
```

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, and this is good information, but I'm going to hold out for a little while before accepting this. Sometimes I'm surprised with the black magic voodoo people come up with.

Comment: @RandyHall: Sadly, in this case, I'm fairly certain no voodoo is available. :-) See the previous answer (originally from 2011) linked above.

Comment: Since you seem to get where I'm going with this...
Javascript attempts to find a property, and if it can't be found, attempts to find that property in prototype (from my understanding) - could something along the lines of Foo.prototype.prototype work? Can I catch javascript sniffing through the prototype layer and react to that?

Comment: @RandyHall: Sadly, no. It's simply not possible to intercept that operation today (except on Firefox). This is *why* proxies are being added to the next edition of the standard. :-)

Comment: @RandyHall You can have a look at Google Dart which compiles to JS and supports proxies in a cross-browser way or use an approach like described in my answer. However the approach I describe implies a change in design and has a performance impact.

Comment: @plalx: That's interesting, can you point me at a Dart example allowing you to catch access to an undefined property?

Comment: @plalx I think in dart it scans all code and see if undefined properties are requested, if there are it'll create those properties. Kind of like the reverse of removing dead code in Google Closure Compiler but then in reverse. So no JS magic there, just Dart knowing what properties to add to the compiled code based on the full project.

Comment: @HMR I haven't read about implementation details, however Dart has a `noSuchMethod` concept that can be utilized with the `@proxy` annotation (to avoid warnings). Have a look at http://blog.dartwatch.com/2012/04/playing-with-nosuchmethod-raises-some.html

Comment: @plalx I would be curious how that is translated to JS but think it's done in the way I described. The compiler scans all the code and any non defined property will point to noSuchmethod. Since all code is already there when compiling Dart knows what properties exist and what properties don't so `myInstance.bananas` is likely compiled to `myInstance.noSuchMethod();` I'll check it out tomorrow; that is if nobody beat me to it.

Comment: @HMR I do not see any other way of implementing this and it's probably the most efficient way of doing it performance-wise so I guess this is it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @LawrenceCherone!

Comment: Is it possible to listen to chained properties with proxy? I mean not just ob.prop, but also obj.prop1.prop2.prop3? to listen whole prop1.prop2.prop3?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili - Unfortunately, to do that you need a chain of proxies. `obj`, `obj.prop1`, and `obj.prop1.propt2` would all have to be proxies.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This would be nice feature. Is it possible to submit feature request or something like that? Where can we do it?

Comment: @TornikeShavishvili - In theory you could write a proposal for TC39 (https://github.com/tc39/proposals), but beware that the bar for that is *very* high, and I don't think it's likely something like this would be accepted into the process (but that's just my view). Remember that `obj.prop1.prop2.prop3` is multiple expressions, and each is handled on its own (`obj.prop1`, then doing `.prop2` on the result of that, then doing `.prop3` on the result of *that*, ...). I also think the utility of it is quite limited, so it's unlikely to outcompete other ideas for resources. Again, just my view. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have same filling :(

Answer (score 5):

I'll write this under the assumption you're trying to debug something. As Crowder said, this is only available on newer browsers; so it's *very* useful for testing code that does something you don't want it to. But, I remove it for production code.

```
Object.defineProperty(Foo, 'bar', {
  set: function() {
    debugger; // Here is where I'll take a look in the developer console, figure out what's
    // gone wrong, and then remove this whole block.
  }
});
```

Looks like megawac beat me to it. You can also find some Mozilla documentation on the features [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 1):

Like answered already, it will only be possible using the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object in ECMAScript6. Meanwhile, depending on your needs and overall design, you can still achieve this by implementing something similar.

E.g.

```
function WrappingProxy(object, noSuchMember) {
    if (!this instanceof WrappingProxy) return new WrappingProxy(object);

    this._object = object;

    if (noSuchMember) this.noSuchMember = noSuchMember;
}

WrappingProxy.prototype = {
    constructor: WrappingProxy,

    get: function (propertyName) {
        var obj = this._object;

        if (propertyName in obj) return obj[propertyName];

        if (this.noSuchMember) this.noSuchMember(propertyName, 'property');
    },

    set: function (propertyName, value) {
        return this._object[propertyName] = value;
    },

    invoke: function (functionName) {
        var obj = this._object, 
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

        if (functionName in obj) return obj[functionName].apply(obj, args);

        if (this.noSuchMember) {
            this.noSuchMember.apply(obj, [functionName, 'function'].concat(args));
        }
    },

    object: function() { return this._object },

    noSuchMember: null
};

var obj = new WrappingProxy({
        testProp: 'test',
        testFunc: function (v) {
            return v;
        }
    },
    //noSuchMember handler
    function (name, type) {
        console.log(name, type, arguments[2]);
    }
);

obj.get('testProp'); //test
obj.get('nonExistingProperty'); //undefined, call noSuchMember
obj.invoke('testFunc', 'test'); //test
obj.invoke('nonExistingFunction', 'test'); //undefined, call noSuchMember

//accesing properties directly on the wrapped object is not monitored
obj.object().nonExistingProperty;
```

Comment: I'm highly intrigued. Can you add a small example usage to this?

Comment: @RandyHall Did you have a look at the very end of the code? There's a usage example. Basically you wrap any object into a `WrappingProxy` and then perform all interactions through method calls (including property access). Basically you would have to avoid using non-wrapped version of your objects if you want this to be consistent. If you have a very specific use case for catching non-existing properties it might be possible to use such an approach.

Comment: Ah alright I see what you're doing there.

Answer (score 0):

With the new `defineProperties`, `defineGetter` and `defineSetter` being added to javascript, you can do something somewhat similar. There is still no true way to hide the `__properties__` of an object however. I suggest you see this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

```
var obj = {
    __properties__: {
        a: 4
    }
}
Object.defineProperties(obj, {
    "b": { get: function () { return this.__properties__.a + 1; } },
    "c": { get: function (x) { this.__properties__.a = x / 2; } }
});

obj.b // 2
obj.c // .5
```

This is the classic sort of model that should work in any environment

```
//lame example of a model
var Model = function(a) {
    this.__properties__ = {a: a};
}

Model.prototype.get = function(item) {
    //do processing
    return this.__properties__[item];
}

Model.prototype.set = function(item, val) {
    //do processing
    this.__properties__[item] = val;
    return this;
}

var model = new Model(5);
model.get("a") // => 5
```

Comment: Good information, but not quite accomplishing what I'm shooting for. I'm trying to prevent "undefined" by defining every property as it's accessed. I want to call a function every time someone tries to access an undefined property of the object, using a function inside the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers mentioned, at the moment there is no way to intercept undefined properties.

Would this be acceptable though?

```
var myObj = (function() {
  var props = {
    foo : 'foo'
  }
  return {
    getProp : function(propName) { return (propName in props) ? props[propName] : 'Nuh-uh!' }
  }
}());

console.log(myObj.getProp('foo')); // foo
console.log(myObj.getProp('bar')); // Nuh-uh
```

Comment: Your idea works nicely for custom forms in React.js, thanks!