# javascript method to catch assigning to missing property

Tags: javascript

I know this has probably been asked everywhere but I'm not sure what it's called to look for it.  Basically I have a javascript object:

```
var foo = Class.create();
foo.prototype = {
   ...
};
```

At this point, if somebody says `myFooObject.bar = 7` I'd like it to hit some special method as `bar` is not defined, where I get the key (bar) and the value (7) and then I can do whatever with it.

Comment: Possibly relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147081/javascript-catch-access-to-property-of-object

Comment: You can only do this with [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) which are part of ECMA Script 6 specs and are not yet fully supported.