# Javascript: Hack object to return a default value insteadof unknown when accessing not exist properity

Tags: javascript

I know that this feal crazy but is there a way to return a value when accessing not exist property of an object in `Javascript`

**For example**

```
function Func(){
        this.msg='hello'
}
var obj= new Func();
alert(obj.msg) // hello
alert(obj.foo) // undefined
```

Are there a way for `obj.foo` to return a defult value not `undefined` rather than `alert(obj.hasOwnProperty('foo'):obj.foo||'foo')`

Comment: Probably this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147081/javascript-catch-access-to-property-of-object