# Node.js + Mongoose set Fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update almost all the fields in my schema except for _id and __v, here's the code so far:

```
for (var field in SchemaTarget.schema.paths) {
       if ((field !== '_id') && (field !== '__v')) {
            //all fields except _id and __v
       }
    }
```

now, how can I set for example: `doc.field = something;`? Also I've seen this: `doc[field] = something`, what's the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doc.field=something
```

It is dot notation of accessing a property of a object.'field' must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

```
doc[field] = something
```

It is bracket notation of accessing a property of a object.'field' is a string. The string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

To know in detail about those, take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) .

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Actually, I have another question, in my code I'm printing `doc.field.field2` and `doc['field.field2']` and they have different values, is this normal? shouldn't both have the same value?

Comment: In the bracket notation you have to use `doc['field']['field2']`

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in javascript or in Mongoose for using the property or the hash accessor.

Mongoose uses the newer "get" magic property, described in detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7891968/68567

You can see it if you look at the code:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/bin/mongoose.js#L1549