# Automatically call a function when accessing an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multithreading, web-worker

I am currently on a big Javascript project with a lot of libraries.
I would like to have some part of this project to run on separate thread. There is already something inJavascript doing that : the web workers.

Though, the web workers can't access the `window` object, and a lot of the libraries use it. Is there a way to automatically change the call to the window object (in the libraries used for the web workers), into a message sent to the parent thread ?

Then, the parent thread would perform the action that the worker want and send back the result to the worker.

Is it possible to do that ? And id yes, do you have any idea how ?

Thank you !

Comment: Try reading about [Worker.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage).

Comment: I am well aware of this function and it's sure I will use it to perform what I want to do.
Though, what I am looking for is how to call this function automatically each time I want to access to the `window` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no real solution to this. What you'd probably want is a special object in your worker, which, at every property access, passes the execution to the dispatching thread - which handles the request using the original window object.

To do this, you would need some sort of catch-all accessor method which would run whenever a property is referenced. Sadly, there's no such thing in Javascript, see this detailed discussion  (especially T.J. Crowder's answer): [Is it possible to implement dynamic getters/setters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript)

ECMAScript 6 introduces a new mechanism called [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) (currently supported in FF and IE12 (*go figure!*)), which would enable you to do these dynamic property lookups, technically - but I feel there's a more fundamental problem with your idea: you're aiming to turn a local call into a message across the boundaries of single threaded environments.

Message passing from and to the worker threads must be asynchronous (as a javascript "thread" cannot be interrupted until it yields), which would mean that even if you do manage to set up a proxy like that, it'd be effectively turning a usually synchronous operation (ie. a property access) into an asynchronous one, which is a pretty big issue, especially if you're looking for a drop-in replacement in order to use some existing libraries.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer and the links !
Well, I guess I will have to figure out another way then !