# Implementation of Javascript class generic setter (modifying setter without knowing the property name)

Tags: javascript, class, generics

Originally my objective is when any property of the instances of class `OnlyOneProp` is set,
i.e. `obj.what_ever_property = "value"`,
at last it will only modify `obj.the_only_prop`.

Behavior is like this:

```
var obj = new OnlyOneProp();
obj.what_ever_property = "value";
console.log(obj.only_property, obj.what_ever_property);
// expected output:
// >value undefined
```

Original Question: Is there a way to implement above behaviour?

edit:

With respect to the [solution in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48436777/3142238),
here are some follow up questions:

1) Is there any major flaw to the above code? (Like I had once mixed up `receiver` and `target`, which may cause infinite looping on the setter)

2) Would `Proxy` hinder the performance a lot?

3) Is there any way to bypass the above proxy setter? (Like `defineProperty()`or so)

4) It can also be an implementation of ReadOnlyObject (after removing the setting line in setter), but would there be a better implementation? (It's a bit out of topic but I also want to know, because I really want to remove the top Proxy which is just overriding the constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return an object from the constructor, the `new` operator returns that object, not the new object it passed to the constructor as `this`. So a more straight forward version of `OnePropertyClass` might be

```
class OnePropertyClass{
    constructor( value) {
        var self = this;
        return new Proxy( this, {
           set: function(target, property, value) {
                    self["only_property"] = value;
                    return true;
                }
           }
        );
    }
}
```

This can be simplified by using an arrow function instead of the closure:

```js
class OnePropertyClass{
    constructor() {
        return new Proxy( this, {
           set: (target, property, value) => {
                    this.only_property = value;
                    return true;
                }
           }
        );
    }
}

var obj = new OnePropertyClass();
obj.what_ever_property = "value";
console.log(obj.only_property, obj.what_ever_property);
```

It doesn't set up any setter loops because the setter stores the value on the actual `this` object of the constructor, not on the proxy object returned.

Instances of this version of `OnePropertyClass` inherit per usual - the `constructor` property returns the `OnePropertyClass` constructor function, and `Object.prototype` properties and methods are still inherited.

You may wish to freeze `OnePropertyClass.prototype` to prevent additions of any other inherited properties. You may also wish to provide trap functions for `defineProperty` and possibly `setPrototype` to prevent run time property additions - see [MDN handler object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#Methods_of_the_handler_object) for details.

Proxy implementation is probably written in C++ and I would *expect* most of the additional overheads will lie in calling the setter function.

I have not tested this version for extensibility and did not use the `target` parameter of the `set` handler Please experiment before use :-)

Comment: oh thank you I once thought the return value from the constructor is useless as I tried it with returning string, now I know that it has to be a ["complex" object](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2522-providing-a-return-value-in-a-javascript-constructor.htm). Returning from constructor certainly make the code more clean and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

After digging up from [MDN Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) and inspiration from [dynamic setter/getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript),

I've come up with the code below:

```
var OnlyOneProp = new Proxy(
    // target
    class{// normal class definition
        constructor(){
            // console.log("anonymous constructor");
        }
    }, {
    construct(target, args, caller){
        // if(!new.target){}
        // console.log("proxy construct");
        return new Proxy(new target(), {
            set(target, name, value, receiver){
                target.only_property = value;
                return true; // must have according to some specification
            }
        });
    },
});

var obj = new OnlyOneProp();
obj.what_ever_property = "value";
console.log(obj.only_property, obj.what_ever_property);
// output: value undefined
```

It's fully functioning but as you may see there are two `new Proxy()` instantiation (although the first one only execute once), which I want to remove if possible.

Comment: solve my origin objective where an object only has one property

Comment: You can accept your own Answer if the Question is resolved

Comment: I was told to wait 2 days for buffer.