# Is it possible to intercept getters/setter calls in Javascript? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know it's possible in Javascript to have an object run a certain code when a non-existing method is called (with Proxies). But is it possible to do the same for non-existing properties?

That is, I'd like to say

```
object.field1 = true
console.log(object.field1)
```

And on both getter and setter calls have my own code run instead of values being assigned and retrieved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript

Comment: It's the same process. Non-existing methods are basically non-existing properties.