# How to generate getters and setters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, local-storage, getter-setter

I have the following code, which is very repetitious:

```
const flags = {
  get logged() {
    return localStorage.getItem("logged") === "true";
  },
  set logged(val: boolean) {
    if (val) {
      localStorage.setItem("logged", "true");
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("logged");
    }
  },
  get notificationsMuted() {
    return localStorage.getItem("notifications-muted") === "true"; 
  },
  set notificationsMuted(val: boolean) {
    if (val) {
      localStorage.setItem("notifications-muted", "true");
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem("notifications-muted");
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `get` and `set` for each flag type is identical, save for the property names. I would like to do something like this instead:

```
function getter(prop: string) {
  return localStorage.getItem(prop) === "true";
}

function setter(prop: string, val: boolean) {
  if (val) {
    localStorage.setItem(prop, "true");
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem(prop);
  }
}

const flags = {
  get logged: getter("logged")
  set logged: setter("logged")
  get notificationsMuted: getter("notifications-muted")
  set notificationsMuted: setter("notifications-muted")
}
```

But I'm not sure if Javascript / Typescript has support for this sort of thing. Is such a thing possible, and if so, how? If not, is there any other way I can cut down on the repetition here?

Comment: Your `getter()` and `setter()` functions should return functions that do what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891937/is-it-possible-to-implement-dynamic-getters-setters-in-javascript

Comment: @Pointy I tried that as well, but it still is erroring out saying the expression is not callable.

Comment: If you're working in Typescript, you have to provide the type information for the return values also.

Comment: @jonrsharpe huh? I did show my attempt in my original post. I didn't know proxies were required for something this basic. I'll just use those if there is no other way

Comment: @Pointy I supplied the return values as well and it's still giving the same error

Comment: I have an example in this repo https://github.com/bluebrown/reactive-effects. One way is defining the props and the other is using object proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/get) and [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) traps, use TS types to allow only props you wish to handle ([TS playground)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4HMDOyDeAUMicugPZZYQAmAXMgEbnnoRwgA0xpA5COTDAYwBHCHkQOALQBbAK6QavBs1bsQAbkIBfQoTABPAA4oAClHLHkAXmQBrCIfIw0mXNsIJJOMMgAWHDRsUHh2RCTUYAAUAPoMGNg4nMjGlsYMFlYAlASkPCRQEGDyUCBk5GLoAMpg5FDYEAB0UQCSkLLRaTm2NnYARGBQ8hD92iQ63CQ8OMVxCe7JqemZ6SkAbnDoDByGuRGkwsjRm+j7BaQUVbX1jU2zYO0Qnd3GKYPDo9njpDrIEOhZgQLiQrlsbg1qE0irJyOsIE8Xulvhc9BciiUysghiMfnodJ5vFI-DBFrZkCAIAB3ZBZAAehgAPIlcAA+aL4P5wPAspaBEDBaA4FGEUlJADavAoVFovAAuvoxbhJdLqMo5eScRBFYtJWIwDh5cgAPTG-5QSxQQhAA)):

```
interface Flags {
  logged: boolean,
  'notifications-muted': boolean;
}

type Prop = keyof Flags;

const handlers = {
  get(_: Flags, prop: Prop) {   
    return localStorage.getItem(prop) === "true";
  },
  
  set(_: Flags, prop: Prop, val: any) {
    if (val) {
      localStorage.setItem(prop, "true");
    } else {
      localStorage.removeItem(prop);
    }

    return true;
  }
};

const flags = new Proxy<Flags>({} as Flags, handlers);
```

Comment: Updated answer to use TS to block props that are not part of `Flags`.

Answer (score 1):

All you really need is to use `Object.defineProperty` with an object with a `get` and `set` properties. Or, with multiple properties, use `Object.defineProperties` to define them all at once.

One approach which will help with code organization is to not use lots of local storage keys, but instead use a single object that gets stored.

```
const props = ['logged', 'notificationsMuted'] as const;
const defaultStorage = Object.fromEntries(props.map(prop => [prop, false]));
const getStorage = () => JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('settings') || JSON.stringify(defaultStorage));
const flags = Object.defineProperties(
    {},
    Object.fromEntries(
        props.map(
            prop => [
                prop,
                {
                    get: () => getStorage()[prop],
                    set: (newVal: boolean) => {
                        const store = getStorage();
                        store.prop = newVal;
                        localStorage.setItem('settings', JSON.stringify(store));
                    }
                }
            ]
        )
    )
) as Record<(typeof props)[number], boolean>;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the current "best" solution I can come up with. Open to anyone who can provide an improvement over this:

```
function getter(prop: string): boolean {
  return localStorage.getItem(prop) === "true";
}

function setter(prop: string, val: boolean): void {
  if (val) {
    localStorage.setItem(prop, "true");
  } else {
    localStorage.removeItem(prop);
  }
}

const flags = {
  get logged() { return getter("logged") },
  set logged(val: boolean) { setter("logged", val) },
  get notificationsMuted() { return getter("notifications-muted"); },
  set notificationsMuted(val: boolean) { setter("notifications-muted", val); }
}
```